# When sorting a folder and it's subfolder, add values to previously created array

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to sort through a folder and it's subfolder to find files that start with a specific name (in this case files called *BACAPPC*.xml).

I save the name of that file to an array. Once I know where the file is located, there is another file in a related folder that I want to add to the array.

The code below finds the two file names and enters them into the array after the first *BACAPPC*.xml file is found, however when the DoFolder sub gets called again to search a new set of folders, it initializes the array and wipes the previously stored values.

```vb
Sub FindAllXMLinAUserSpecifiedFolder2()
' First ask user for the file path to search for the XML files

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    ' temp comment out call dialog box and force path name
    sItem = "C:\UserData\hawkib\XXXX\YYYY\Job_10-18-22"
    
    'Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    'With fldr
    '    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    '    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    '    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    '    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    '    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    'End With
'NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
'    Set fldr = Nothing


' more stuff

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    HostFolder = GetFolder
        
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder), 1
End Sub
    
Sub DoFolder(folder, RowNum As Integer)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim ExtSplit As Variant
    Dim NameSplit As Variant
    Dim TempName As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim file
    Dim AppFileLocs() As Variant
    Dim AppTypeInfoLocation As String
    Dim Split1 As Variant
    Dim Split2 As Variant
    
    For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
        TempName = SubFolder
        If InStr(1, SubFolder, "TPL_", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    
            For Each file In SubFolder.Files
                TempFileName = file
                If file Like "*BAAPPC_*.xml" Then
                    ' prints file to excel - for testing only
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 1) = file
                    ReDim Preserve AppFileLocs(RowNum - 1, 2)
                    AppFileLocs(RowNum - 1, 0) = file
                    ExtSplit = Split(file, ".")
                    NameSplit = Split(file, "\")

                    Flpath = Left(file, Len(file) - Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))))
                    Spilt1 = Split(Flpth, "\")
                    ' find name of parent folder and then append to change directory to parent folder\APPTYPE then include name of file that will be added to the array
                    Split1 = Left(SubFolder, InStrRev(SubFolder, "\") - 1) & "\APPTYPE\AppTypeInfo.xml"
                    AppFileLocs(RowNum - 1, 1) = Split1
                
                    RowNum = RowNum + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
        
        DoFolder SubFolder, RowNum
    Next

End Sub
```

How so I search all folders and subfolders and add the file names to an array?

Comment: If all `TPL_` folders are in the root folder (not in its subfolders), you don't need to complicate with recursion. If the folder names start with `TPL_` you should use `If Instr(...) = 1 Then`. You have a typo: `BACAPPC.xml` will not be found using `*BAAPPC_*.xml` neither will `BAAPPC.xml`. Note that the comparison using the *Like* operator is case-sensitive (`"A"<>"a"`). What are you planning to do with the resulting array? Please add any additional information to your post and apply any necessary corrections.

Comment: The TPL folders are not in the root, under the root are folders named APPCNT_XXXX, inside those folders are the TPL_ folders, inside those folders are the XML files I am looking for. The XML files are named BAAPPC_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>XML, which is why I used the wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using a non-recursive search over subfolders, then processing the list of found files:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

    Dim xmlFiles As Collection, rootFolder As String, xmlFile, appFileLocs As Collection
    
    rootFolder = "C:\UserData\hawkib\XXXX\YYYY\Job_10-18-22"
    
    Set xmlFiles = GetFileMatches(rootFolder, "*BAAPPC_*.xml")
    Set appFileLocs = New Collection
    
    For Each xmlFile In xmlFiles
        Debug.Print xmlFile.Path
        appFileLocs.Add xmlFile.parentfolder.Path & "\APPTYPE\AppTypeInfo.xml"
    Next xmlFile
    
    'do something with `appFileLocs`

End Sub

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFileMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder

    Do While colSub.Count > 0

        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        'collect any subfolders
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        '### collect any matching files only if the folder name contains "TPL_"
        If InStr(1, fldr.Name, "TPL_", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            For Each f In fldr.Files
                If f.Name Like filePattern Then colFiles.Add f
            Next f
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFileMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, I didn't clarify in my original post that the XML files I'm looking for are two folders below the root. In the root, are multiple APPCNT folders, each APPCNT_XXXX folder contains a TPL_XXXX, I'm looking for the names of the XML files within the TPL_XXXX folder. My understanding, (which is pretty minimal) is that since I was looking through nested folders, the only way to do that was to do a recursive search, can I modify what you have above to search folder within subfolders?

Comment: I made some edits in `GetFileMatches` and I think that's now closer to what you want.  Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Folders of Folders of a Folder

- Since you know the depth level of the folders you need, you can avoid using recursion or other methods to find all subfolders of a folder.
- Since you have access to the *FileSystemObject* object, you also have access to the *Dictionary* object. It is a more appropriate data structure to be used instead of an array.

```vb
Sub GetXmlFilePairs()

    Const ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String _
        = "C:\UserData\hawkib\XXXX\YYYY\Job_10-18-22"
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Each key will contain the 'baappc...' file path while each corresponding
    ' item will contain the 'AppTypeInfo.xml' file path.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object, fsoSubFolder As Object, fsoFile As Object
    Dim SubFolderPath As String, SubFilePath As String
    
    ' Level 1: all folders of the root folder
    For Each fsoFolder In fso.GetFolder(ROOT_FOLDER_PATH).Subfolders
        ' Level 2: all folders of all folders of the root folder
        For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
            If InStr(1, fsoSubFolder.Name, "TPL_", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' contains
            'If InStr(1, fsoSubFolder.Name, "TPL_", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then ' begins with
                SubFolderPath = fsoSubFolder.Path
                For Each fsoFile In fsoSubFolder.Files
                    If LCase(fsoFile.Name) Like "baappc_*.xml" Then ' begins with / ends with
                    'If LCase(fsoFile.Name) Like "*baappc_*.xml" Then ' contains / ends with
                        SubFilePath = fso _
                            .BuildPath(SubFolderPath, "APPTYPE\AppTypeInfo.xml")
                        If fso.FileExists(SubFilePath) Then
                            dict(fsoFile.Path) = SubFilePath
                        Else
                            dict(fsoFile.Path) = ""
                        End If
                        ' If you're looking for a single file per folder
                        ' (looks like it), you could improve efficiency with:
                        'Exit For
                    End If
                Next fsoFile
            End If
        Next fsoSubFolder
    Next fsoFolder
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Print the paths of the file pairs in the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
    
    Dim Key
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print Key, dict(Key)
    Next Key

    ' Return the paths of the file pairs in a worksheet.
    
'    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count)
'        .Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
'        .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
'    End With
    ' Note that this simplification wouldn't be possible
    ' if you used a collection instead of the dictionary.

End Sub
```